# HTML Table adjustments: How to adjust the font type and the aligning of text in HTML at the same time?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am currently trying to edit a HTML table.

My goal is to adjust the font type to Arial. My idea was to add this row above the second row of the code sample provided below:

```
style='font-family:"Arial", Courier, monospace; font-size:100%'
```

When I insert this to the code below above the second row, my table is in Arial. But, the text is no longer aligned in the center. Is it possible to just change the font size with leaving the rest of the table formatting untouched?

Thank you very much!

This is the code of the table:

```html
<table style="text-align:center">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="5" style="border-bottom: 1px solid black"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="text-align:left"></td>
    <td colspan="4"><em>Dependent variable:60_day_sum</em></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="text-align:left"></td>
    <tr>
      <td style="text-align:left"></td>
      <td>(1)
      </td>
      <td>(2)</td>
      <td>(3)</td>
      <td>(4)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="5" style="border-bottom: 
    1px solid black"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="text-align:left">b_m</td>
      <td>0.017<sup></sup>
      </td>
      <td>0.017<sup></sup></td>
      <td>0.015<sup></sup></td>
      <td>0.019<sup></sup></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="text-align:left"></td>
      <td>(0.088)</td>
      <td>(0.088)</td>
      <td>(0.088)</td>
      <td>(0.088)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="text-align:left">mcap</td>
      <td>-0.141<sup></sup></td>
      <td>-0.175<sup></sup></td>
      <td>-0.166<sup></sup></td>
      <td>-0.159<sup></sup></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="text-align:left"></td>
      <td>(0.155)</td>
      <td>(0.155)</td>
      <td>(0.155)</td>
      <td>
        (0.155)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="text-align:left">previous_month_ret</td>
      <td>-0.852<sup>***</sup></td>
      <td>-0.877<sup>***</sup></td>
      <td>-0.851<sup>***</sup></td>
      <td>-0.855<sup>***</sup></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="text-align:left"></td>
      <td>(0.114)</td>
      <td>(0.113)</td>
      <td>(0.113)</td>
      <td>(0.113)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="text- 
    align:left">short_term_ret</td>
      <td>0.664<sup>***</sup></td>
      <td>0.658<sup>***</sup></td>
      <td>0.657<sup>***</sup></td>
      <td>0.667<sup>***</sup></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="text- 
    align:left"></td>
      <td>(0.105)</td>
      <td>(0.105)</td>
      <td>(0.105)</td>
      <td>(0.105)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="text-align:left">short_term_vol</td>
      <td>1.514<sup>***</sup></td>
      <td>1.522<sup>***</sup></td>
      <td>1.498<sup>***</sup></td>
      <td>1.511<sup>***</sup></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="text-align:left"></td>
      <td>(0.161)</td>
      <td>(0.161)</td>
      <td>(0.161)
      </td>
      <td>(0.161)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="text-align:left">long_term_vol</td>
      <td>1.568<sup>***</sup></td>
      <td>1.531<sup>***</sup></td>
      <td>1.513<sup>***</sup></td>
      <td>1.519<sup>***</sup></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="text-align:left"></td>
      <td>(0.197)</td>
      <td>(0.197)</td>
      <td>(0.197)</td>
      <td>(0.197)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="text- 
    align:left">momentum_ret</td>
      <td>-1.401<sup>***</sup></td>
      <td>-1.393<sup>***</sup></td>
      <td>-1.373<sup>***</sup></td>
      <td>-1.361<sup>***</sup></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="text- 
    align:left"></td>
      <td>(0.109)</td>
      <td>(0.108)</td>
      <td>(0.108)</td>
      <td>(0.108)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="text-align:left">earnings_surprise</td>
      <td>0.120<sup>***</sup></td>
      <td>0.126<sup>***</sup></td>
      <td>0.138<sup>***</sup></td>
      <td>0.136<sup>***</sup></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="text-align:left"></td>
      <td>(0.029)</td>
      <td>(0.029)</td>
      <td>(0.029)
      </td>
      <td>(0.029)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="text-align:left">net_pres_fin</td>
      <td>0.561<sup>***</sup></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="text- 
    align:left"></td>
      <td>(0.121)</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="text- 
    align:left">net_qanda_fin</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>0.920<sup>***</sup></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="text-align:left"></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>(0.111)</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="text-align:left">net_analyst_fin</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>0.556<sup>***</sup></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="text-align:left"></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>(0.096)</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="text-align:left">net_corp_fin</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>0.768<sup>***</sup></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="text- 
    align:left"></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>(0.107)</td>
    </tr>
    <td colspan="5" style="border-bottom: 1px solid black"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="text-align: 
    left">Observations</td>
    <td>44,014</td>
    <td>44,014</td>
    <td>44,014</td>
    <td>44,014</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="text-align: left">R<sup>2</sup></td>
    <td>0.093</td>
    <td>0.094</td>
    <td>0.093</td>
    <td>0.094</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="text-align: left">Adjusted R<sup>2</sup>
    </td>
    <td>0.053</td>
    <td>0.054</td>
    <td>0.054</td>
    <td>0.054</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="text- 
    align: left">Residual Std. Error</td>
    <td>18.216 (df=42159)</td>
    <td>18.206 (df=42159)
    </td>
    <td>18.213 (df=42159)</td>
    <td>18.209 (df=42159)</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="text-align: 
    left">F Statistic</td>
    <td>2.336<sup>***</sup> (df=1854; 42159)</td>
    <td>2.364<sup>*** 
    </sup> (df=1854; 42159)</td>
    <td>2.343<sup>***</sup> (df=1854; 42159)</td>
    <td>2.353<sup>***</sup> (df=1854; 42159)</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="5" style="border- 
    bottom: 1px solid black"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="text-align: left">Note:</td>
    <td colspan="4" style="text-align: right">
      <sup>*</sup>p&lt;0.1;
      <sup>**</sup>p&lt;0.05;
      <sup>***</sup>p&lt;0.01
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: hello Kyle thanks for asking a question... but we need clarity in your question. explanation needed. explain what result you want at the last. this explanation is not enough..? by the way what does "above the second row" mean? your question totally messed.. at first you say "My goal is to adjust the font type to Arial".  then you say "but the text is no longer align to the center". then you say "want to change font-size"..